# Finding Duplicates in Large Table Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I want to show how the rows that appear more than once in a very large table with over 40 columns in a Oracle Database, and eventually clean up the duplicates. I know the simplest way to do it by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ...
FROM schema.tablename
GROUP BY field1, field2, ...
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But I want to know if there is a simpler way to list duplicates in ORACLE since the table I need to work with has a large number of fields, so listing them in the SELECT and GROUP BY clause would be very inefficient and long. Is there a way to list all columns from a table within the SELECT and GROUP BY clause like this?

```
SELECT all_columns(tablename)
FROM schema.tablename
GROUP BY all_columns(tablename)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Or, is there a better method for finding duplicates in an ORACLE table? Thanks for the help!

Comment: To clarify, your concern is not about query performance, but how to "write" the query in an easy way. Is that correct?

Comment: As of Oracle 21c you can use `select * from mytable except all select distinct * from mytable;` to select the duplicates. Ths doesn't help you at all with the intended deletion, though.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - not to mention that that query will do the same aggregation as in the answer I posted, then it will read the base table again for the set operation, and then it still has to perform the set operation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that comes close. Note - this would work if your table has only 40 columns; it may not work if it has 400 columns, say, each with a name length of 10 characters on average. (The bottleneck is the 4000 character limit for the whole string, and especially the limit on `listagg`; apparently this isn't an issue in your case, so I won't talk about workarounds.)

You can write a query against `all_tab_columns`, which will produce as its **output** the query you actually need. Copy the output and paste it back into your editor where you run queries, then run the query.

I am showing this for table `EMP` in schema `SCOTT` - adapt as needed.

```
select 'select * from SCOTT.EMP group by ' ||
       listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id) ||
       ' having count(*) > 1;' as sql_str
from   all_tab_columns
where  owner = 'SCOTT'
  and  table_name = 'EMP'
;

SQL_STR                                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select * from scott.emp group by EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO having count(*) > 1;
```

If, after you inspect the duplicate rows, you decide you need to remove the duplicates, you can do something like

```
delete from [table]
where  rowid not in ( select min(rowid) from [table] group by ...  )
```

where the grouping is by the same set of all columns. That is - modify the FIRST query, the one that produces the query you actually want to run, to take this form instead.